# How to remove Chromium from programs and features windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, malware, chromium, control-panel, unwanted-application

Through a downloaded program a chromium browser got installed as well, unwanted.

As suggested in other topics concerning this matter I've deleted chromium from `%Appdata%` and program files. 
Are there more locations this unwanted program could be hidden? It is still showing up in my programs and features and clicking delete on it does nothing.

Should I check for malware, viruses or malicious content on my computer now?

Edit: 
in my `%Appdata\Local\Temp%`I've found all kind of installers and files without any extension. I have deleted this but how do I get rid of this problem, where else might it be? Concerning is my virus scanner does not mention anything. I've also found in my `Sytem32`folder new files created at the same time as chromium in tasks, drivers and installers.

Comment: By clearing the Temp directory, before you removed this unwanted program, you have made it difficult to remove it.  I suggest downloading the current Chromium installer, then after it is installed, uninstall Chromium.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

- Close the web browser and open the Task Manager tool. Find all chrome.exe/chromium.exe processes to terminate them.
- Open Control Panel and switch #] to the Program and features menu. Find Chromium and uninstall it.
- Open hidden folder C:\Users\\AppData\Local and wipe the Chromium folder. If Google Chrome is your main the folder you have just deleted will appear again automatically with the data.
- Open the web browser and check all extensions and add-ons. Delete every suspicious item as they might be installed by a malware.
- Run a full PC scan using an antimalware tool or antivirus. It will find the left files of malware and delete it.

You can read more at https://rocketfiles.com/articles/how-to-remove-chromium-malware-from-windows-10. Hope it will be useful and will help you.

Answer (score -1):

yes. The next step for you now is to scan your PC with anti-malware tools. It detects any possible threats. Since Chromium can seed its pieces all over, you should scan the whole system. It might help to remove it later on. Also, there might by other unwanted programs which cause your system issues. It is intrusive so uninstalling might get you nowhere. The scan is for the better. Good luck!